# Serialize Labelencoder in sklearn

Tags: serialization, encoding, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a huge dataset and I have column where there are some categorical data which I want to label encode. After all the preprocessing i can train my model and serialize the model using sklearn.

Now I am faced with a problem that , if a input prediction vector consist of labels how do i encode that at that point. Since I don't want preprocess and retrain the model everytime a new input prediction vector comes in. Is there a way to serialize labelencoder in sklearn? What would be the right approach in this problem ?

Comment: You can just pickle it, the same way you did with your classifier (I'm guessing).

Answer (score 0):

As ncfirth mentions in his comment - The correct way to do this is to serialize it the same way you serialized the classifier (Usually pickle/joblib).